# Can't get into a wall without gouging it out

Tags: walls, mounting, nails

My house was built in 1948 and is in [St. Louis County, Missouri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Louis_County,_Missouri). I don't know what its walls are made of, but nothing is on them except paint [AFAICT](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/AFAICT). For many of the walls, whenever I try to hammer a nail in, it won't go in more than a couple of millimeters or so; after that all I can do is bend the nail. Attempting to get into the wall with a drill or a "self-drilling anchor" yields a gouged-out wall rather than a clean hole. (The material inside, and gouged out, is grainy.) I seek suggestion, please, for getting something (preferably a nail) in my wall cleanly. (I simply want to hang some pictures!)

---

Most of the examples of this have already been painted over, so here is the only one I can find: it's the result of attempting to hammer a thin nail into the wall.
[image: photo]

Comment: [Previously asked on Usenet with no success.](https://groups.google.com/group/alt.home.repair/browse_frm/thread/3b93c7227297ac6c)

Comment: A picture truly is worth a thousand words - in this case, a picture of one of your gouged-out previous attempts, so we can make an educated guess as to what your wall is made of.  I do think that pre-drilling the hole will be your best bet - the question is, what kind of drill/bit?

Comment: Without the picture, I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that you've got plaster over chicken wire; you're probably getting extremely unlucky and hitting a wire each time.  If I'm right about that, I think I would just try a different bit - bimetallic or carbide, so it can cut through steel - and proceed slowly and carefully.

Comment: I called it "chicken wire", but this is what I was referring to: http://amico-lath.com/lath/diamond_metal_lath.htm

Comment: @MT_Head - A picture "can" be worth a thousand words. In the case of the picture posted by msh210 the picture is basically worthless.

Comment: Epic photography fail.

Comment: Epic Posting Fail too.

Comment: Is it possible you have a plastered wall over masonry block wall?

Comment: @shirlockhomes, beats me.

Answer (score 2):

To hang your pictures you could use a fixture like a 3M command hook designed expressly for hanging pictures on walls without using nails or drills.

[image]